# Sangria GraphQL Schema with EitherT result

Tags: scala, playframework, graphql, scala-cats, sangria

I'm using Sangria for a Play application and currently struggling to implement the schema definition. The Problem is, that the service does not return the needed object directly, it returns an EitherT containing the object.

Here are some code examples

*case class*

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
```

*UserService*

```
def user(): EitherT[Future, AbstractError, User] = {...}
```

If the service would return a `User` instead of a `EitherT[Future, AbstractError, User]` I would derive the schema like this:

*Schema*

```
  val UserType = deriveObjectType[UserService, User]( 
      ObjectTypeName("User"),
      ObjectTypeDescription("A simple user."))
```

Do I have to implement an additional layer to extract the `User` from the `EitherT` object or is there another way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still derive the `User` object type since it is just a simple case class. For other GraphQL fields that load the users and return `EitherT` you would need to transform the value to something that sangria can work with (which means that these fields need to be defined manually, but you still can use `derive*` macros for other fields). The most simple approach would be to fold it to a simple `Future[User]`. `Future` is able to hold the error or the success result. If you would have a list of errors inside of the `Either`, then you can just wrap it in some custom exception, and then unwrap and properly render it in the `ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Thank you tenshi. I will try your solution. 

And btw. Sangria is great, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an implicit conversion from cats `EitherT` to a sangria `FutureValue` somewhere in your schema :

```
implicit def eithertAction[Ctx, Val, E <: Throwable](value: EitherT[Future, E, Val]): ReduceAction[Ctx, Val] = FutureValue(value.valueOrF(Future.failed))
```